# when we run composer update on magento version 2.4.2-p1 facing issue

Tags: magento2

**Facing the issue of during composer update on magento 2.4.2-p1**

Uncaught Error: Interface 'Laminas\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface' not found in /home/moazzam/www/test.local/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Di/MagentoDiFactory.php:17
Stack trace:

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a screenshot of command line error clearly again , because it is difficult to understand the error from this message

Comment: When i run the php bin/magento di:compile then issue is ocuuring on 33%

Comment: Try deleting the vendor/ directory and run composer install so that files which are missing will be re-downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use these commands :

```
rm -rf vendor
composer install
composer update
```

If this is not fix your issue, then you should delete `composer.lock` and then run above three commands.

- `Possibly there will be any patches available from the Adobe Side`

If the problem still continues, then ping me again!